# 'Sum if' no MySql workbench

Tags: sql, mysql

Tenho um banco no MySql.

```
No_Pedido|Valor|Cortesia
123|1000|Sim
123|500|Nao
124|200|Nao
124|500|Nao
```

Preciso fazer um select que me retorne a soma do valor por pedido que não seja cortesia,

seria um `sumif`..

O Select precisa ficar assim:

```
No_Pedido|Valor|Cortesia
123|500|Nao
124|700|Nao
```

To usando a seguinte query:

```
select sum(case when cortesia = 'Sim' then valor else 0 end) from tabela;
```

E o resultado não é como o esperado...

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual o resultado que você está tendo e por que ele não é o esperado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o resultado esperado você deve agrupar por número do pedido e cortesia e não tentar separar em colunas diferentes.

```
select No_Pedido,
       sum(valor),
       Cortesia
  from tabela
  group by No_Pedido,
           Cortesia;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trazer somente os registros que lhe interessam e filtrar os demais utilizando a clausula `WHERE`. Veja um exemplo de como ficaria:

```
SELECT No_Pedido, SUM(Valor)
FROM tabela
WHERE cortesia = "nao"
```